# Android + NIO + SSL. Does anyone have some good example code?

Tags: java, android, nio, ssl

I'm looking for some good examplecode that implements a java (Android!) NIO client with SSL support. I've stumbled upon SSLEngine but I'm not sure whether I should even continue to look into that direction since some sources claim that Androids SSLEngine isn't stable.

The server I've implemented is written in Twisted Python and the used factory is implemented as follows:

```
class ServerTLSContextFactory(ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        kw['sslmethod'] = SSL.TLSv1_METHOD
        ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
```

Does anyone have a good implementation (or wrapper for NIO) that I could use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even with SSLEngine doing SSL with NIO is *very* hard to get right. You must get a copy of "Fundamental Networking in Java" by Esmund Pitt.